# "María Llena Eres de Gracia" in English

Tags: traducción, orden-de-palabras

That's the name of a well-known movie from Colombia and also happens to be one of my biggest favorites. But I have always struggled to understand how it translates to "María, Full of Grace" in English. What purpose is that "**eres**" serving there? Shouldn't it just be called "**María, Llena de Gracia**"?

Comment: It plays with the word "llena", as María carries drug in her stomach. Also, note the movie is from Colombia.

Comment: "María, llena de gracia" = "Mary, full of grace" "(María), llena eres de gracia" = "(Mary), you are full of grace"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Simple answer**

Because that's how the original prayer was translated to Spanish.  In English, the same prayer is translated "Hail Mary, full of grace", hence the English translation matching the common English prayer.

**Longer answer** *(regarding the syntax)*

Modern Spanish generally uses what's called a SVO structure (*subject-verb-object*), and more specifically what could be called SVDI (*subject - verb - direct object - indirect object*).  This is seen in sentences like "**S**(Juan) **V**(dio) **D**(los libros) **I**(a María)".  That said, Spanish does allow free ordering of those four elements.  The only restriction is that if the objects come in front of the verb, they must — with a handful of exceptions — also be included as an object pronoun (hence, the IOVD option "A María los libros se los dio Juan" obligates *se los* in front of *dio*).

The other type of element that can move around freely (besides adverbs — out of the scope of this response) are predicative nominatives.  They function like (in)direct objects most of the time with a few small differences.<sup>1</sup>  The sentence you're asking about is "llena eres de gracias".  *Llena* represents a predicate nominative.  Summed up, we have PnV with implied S (tú).   We could respin that and get SVPn which is more common: "Tú eres llena de gracia".  We could also do VSPn: "Eres tú llena de gracia".

Some sentence structures are quite common.  OVS is of course the norm with gustar-type verbs.  SVO is common for declarative.  VOS is most common for interrogative.  Others are heard frequently, even if not the default.  Some of the rarer orders will normally be used when you want to give particular emphasis to one element or another, although it's difficult to explain the exact rules governing that and I'd recommend just going with what you see others use for contrast/emphasis.

**Longer answer** *(regarding the use of* ser *)*

While indeed at first glance it may seem like the verb should be *estar*, this is clear example of where you can't look at *ser* as permanent and *estar* as temporary.<sup>2</sup>  Also, it's important to remember that while some adjectives will almost always be used with one or the other, others can have drastic changes in meaning.  When in doubt, one thing I've found is you can often sneak in the word "una persona" / "una mujer" / un hombre" before and the rationale for *ser* will pop out pretty clearly (and also completely contraindicate *estar*)

- María, tú eres *una mujer* llena de gracia. (good)
- *María, tú estás *una mujer* llena de gracias. (bad)

---

<sup>1. One of the main differences is that its object pronoun is generally the neuter "lo": ¿Es María llena de gracia?  Sí, **lo** es. (although, in reality, you'd rarely use the *lo* in this case).  Also, a predicative nominative generally doesn't ever appear with its object pronoun simultaneously.</sup>

<sup>2. That's probably one of the worst ways, actually, to describe the difference between the two because of the proliferation of contraindications.  If any quick difference is to be used, I'd recommend going with the English cognates: state/estar, and essence/ser.  The nature of pizza (its essence) is that it's hot, while ice cream is cold.  Hence "La pizza es caliente y el helado es frío" when describing them generally.  But the state of something need not line up with its nature.  My slice of pizza may be hot or cold, and in describing that state, I'll use *estar*</sup>

Answer (score 3):

It's The "Hail Mary", which in Spanish goes like this:

> Dios te salve, **María,
>
>   llena eres de gracia**,
>   el Señor es contigo (...)

For a full explanation of why the Spanish prayer is worded like that (using *ser* instead of *estar*, etc.), please see [guifa's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/7122/mar%C3%ADa-llena-eres-de-gracia-in-english/7131#7131).

Comment: This does not answer the question**What purpose is that "eres" serving there?** This is a "just because" answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually "María llena eres de gracia" it's a part of a prayer dedicated towards Mother Mary called "Ave María" or "Hail Mary".

*"Dios te salve María
llena eres de gracia
el Señor es contigo;
bendita tú eres 
entre todas las mujeres,
y bendito es el fruto 
de tu vientre, Jesús. 
Santa María, Madre de Dios,
ruega por nosotros pecadores,
ahora y en la hora
de nuestra muerte. 
Amén"*

As for why the word "eres" is in that sentence, I'm inclined to say that is old Spanish, since this prayer is taken from the bible. It's a way of saying you are full of grace. If there is anyone who can confirm this that would be great.
Hope this helps somehow!

Comment: Actually saying "Maria, you are full of grace" does make sense. However, in that case, shouldn't it translated as "Maria, eres llena de gracia"?

Comment: If it were like that, it should be: "Maria, estás llena de gracia". Unfortunately the way you translated it is incorrect.

Comment: agreed. My confusion, however, is more on the usage of "llena" before "eres" in this sentence that somehow doesn't sound like conventional grammar that I've learned so far.

Comment: The thing is it's not modern Spanish. It's like comparing Elizabethan English or Victorian English to nowadays English. Nobody speaks like that today, semantically it's wrong (I think) using today's rules.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in that grammar. It is just odd because it is not common, but in Spanish there is not a mandatory order of the groups in a sentence, or of the words in a group. For any native speaker "llena eres de gracia" and "eres llena de gracia" means exactly the same, just that the first sounds more ancient or more poetic. About using "eres" instead of "estás", there is a big difference. Mother Mary is not temporarily full of God's grace (that would be "estar"), but she is that way permanently, it is a part of what she is (so it is "ser").

Comment: I disagree with that, @Envite. This is simply an old use of the verb *ser*. The same happens in the next verse (*El Señor es contigo*, instead of *El Señor está contigo*). The verb *estar* can be used for permanent conditions too (*la botella está hecha de cristal*, even though it is made of glass forever and there is no way to change that).

Comment: @Gorpik you are using "estar hecho de" which is a periphrasis, not an isolated meaning of "estar".

Comment: @Envite hecho there just functions as an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

*María, llena eres de Gracia* is not translated *Mary, full of Grace.*

The word ***eres*** means off course ***you are***.

If you translate *Mary, full of Grace* to spanish then you'll have *María, llena de Gracia*.

So the real purpose of *eres* is because it is a prayer, a phrase you are ACTUALLY saying to her, as you were **talking to someone in front of you**. The correct way that prayer would be translated to english is *Mary, you are full of Grace* (talking to her), because if you say *Mary, full of Grace* it could be understood **as you are referring to a third person not a second** as the real purpose of that phrase is.